# отключение мапирования в DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть модель вида:

```
class MyModels(models.Model):
    name = CharhField(max_lenght=100)
    address = CharField(max_lenght=100)
```

Имеется сериализатор вида:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = MyModel
          fields = ('name', 'address', 'code')

      name = CharhField(max_lenght=100)
      address = CharField(max_lenght=100)
      code = CharField(max_lenght=100)
```

То есть сериализатор у меня содержит одно дополнительное поле. Таким образом получается, что "сет":

```
class MyViewSet(CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    queryset = MyModels.objects
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

при сохранении результата падает с ошибкой вида:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `code` on serializer `MySerializer`.
app_1       | The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `MyModel` instance.
app_1       | Original exception text was: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'code'.
```

Эта ошибка происходит в Respone, которые делает MyViewSet. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то убрать этот "code" из validated_data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обозначить поле, отсутствующее в модели, как `write_only=True`, чтобы избежать этой ошибки. И перегрузить метод `create`.

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    code = CharField(max_lenght=100, write_only=True)
    # поля address и name не нужно дублировать в теле сериалайзера

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'address', 'code')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        code = validated_data.pop('code')
        # Проводите нужные операции с полем `code`
        return super(MySerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```